# QWebEngineView - Javascript Callback

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebview

What I am ultimately trying to accomplish is to capture the username and password that the user enters into a website. For example, if the user enters "test@example.com" as the email address into Facebook's login, then clicks submit, I want to store that email address in my PyQt Application.

The closest I've come to achieving this has been using a series of JavaScript commands to place a listener on the "Login Button" that returns the current value of the user parameter. My problem is that the callback that PyQt provides is for when the `runJavaScript` function is completed, not the javascript event listener. I'm wondering if there is any way to capture the callback function from the JavaScript function, or if there is a better way altogether for me to do this.

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QEventLoop
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

class WebPage(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebEngineView.__init__(self)
        self.load(QUrl("https://facebook.com"))
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        #self.page().runJavaScript("document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", displayDate)", print)

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        print("Finished Loading")
        cmds = ["btn=document.getElementById('u_0_r')",  # Login Button
                "user=document.getElementsByName('email')[0]",
                "function get_username(){return user.value}",
                "btn.addEventListener('click', get_username)"]
        self.page().runJavaScript("; ".join(cmds), lambda x: print("test: %s"  % x))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    web = WebPage()
    web.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())  # only need one app, one running event loop
```

Comment: You're trying to capture the username ***and*** password ??

Comment: Yes, the example just shows username/email because (correct me if I'm wrong) the principles should be the same

Comment: But you appear to be trying to steal the users' passwords...

Comment: @ekhumoro Less about stealing and more about remembering / auto-filling the user's password each time they enter the browser. Think dashlane/lastpass/chrome-autofill. Happy to take other suggestions if you have them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a work around using the "urlChanged" signal that seems to work so far for my applications

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QEventLoop
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor

class WebPage(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebEngineView.__init__(self)
        self.current_url = ''
        self.load(QUrl("https://facebook.com"))
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        self.urlChanged.connect(self._on_url_change)

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        self.current_url = self.url().toString()

    def _on_url_change(self):
        self.page().runJavaScript("document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value", self.store_value)

    def store_value(self, param):
        self.value = param
        print("Param: " +str(param))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    web = WebPage()
    web.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())  # only need one app, one running event loop
```