# Display HTML Datalist in PyQT5

Tags: python, html, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I have an HTML page which contains some `<datalist>` elements.
I'm able to run it properly in Chrome but when running it using Python-PyQt5, the Datalist doesn't function as needed (It functions as a text-box i.e. the drop-down isn't displayed).
In Python I'm running it using PyQt5: `load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filepath))`. 
Where the `filepath` is the path for `index.html`.
I've gone through several articles and got to know that HTML Datalist isn't supported in Older Webkit Engines but found some workarounds like: [Datalist-polyfill](https://www.cssscript.com/html-datalist-polyfill-safari/) but they aren't working either.
Is there a workaround for this or Datalist is just not possible here?

HTML Code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>

 <div id="formContainer">
  <form id="mainForm">
   <div class="form-label-group">
    <input list="subject-area" name="subjectArea" class="form-control" placeholder="Select or Enter a Subject Area">
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
 
 <div id="datalistContainer">
  <datalist id="subject-area" class="form-control" style="display: none;">
   <option value="Account" class="form-control">Account</option>
   <option value="Adjustments" class="form-control">Adjustments</option>
   <option value="Alliance Sales" class="form-control">Alliance Sales</option>
   <option value="Assets" class="form-control">Assets</option>
   <option value="Business Plan" class="form-control">Business Plan</option>
   <option value="Calendar" class="form-control">Calendar</option>
   <option value="Chargeback" class="form-control">Chargeback</option>
   <option value="Company" class="form-control">Company</option>
  </datalist>
 </div>
</body>
```

Python Code:

```py
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


class WebPage(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        filepath = os.path.abspath(
            os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "temp.html")
        )
        self.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filepath))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    web = WebPage()
    web.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note: The Python code is not yet updated. All I want to do is to get the `datalist` working for now.

Comment: I'm using QtWebEngine only. Actually it's from your solution itself :P
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55947552/pyqt5-retrieve-form-values-using-runjavascript

Comment: I've edited the question to include the code.