# how to change a part of html in pyqt5 qwebengineview

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I have viewed some html in qwebengineview.setHtml() and now I want to run a python function when clicking a button in that html view and then add some html to my html view which is the output of the function which I've called. In concrete: I want that when the form button is pressed I want the inputs removed.

I have readed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55947552/pyqt5-retrieve-form-values-using-runjavascript) but it doesn't tell me how to make changes in my html or change a part of it or append to it.
Example:

```py
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets, QtWebChannel
from jinja2 import Template


class Element(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        super(Element, self).__init__(parent)
        self._name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    def script(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class FormObject(Element):
    numbersChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, str)

    def script(self):
        _script = r"""
        var btn = document.getElementById('sub1');
        btn.addEventListener("click", function(event){
            var number1 = document.getElementById('num1');
            var number2 = document.getElementById('num2');
            {{name}}.update(number1.value , number2.value);
        });
        """
        return Template(_script).render(name=self.name)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str, str)
    def update(self, number1, number2):
        self.numbersChanged.emit(number1, number2)


class WebEnginePage(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WebEnginePage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.onLoadFinished)
        self._objects = []

    def add_object(self, obj):
        self._objects.append(obj)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)
    def onLoadFinished(self, ok):
        if ok:
            self.load_qwebchannel()
            self.load_objects()

    def load_qwebchannel(self):
        file = QtCore.QFile(":/qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js")
        if file.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly):
            content = file.readAll()
            file.close()
            self.runJavaScript(content.data().decode())
        if self.webChannel() is None:
            channel = QtWebChannel.QWebChannel(self)
            self.setWebChannel(channel)

    def load_objects(self):
        if self.webChannel() is not None:
            objects = {obj.name: obj for obj in self._objects}
            self.webChannel().registerObjects(objects)
            _script = r"""
            {% for obj in objects %}
            var {{obj}};
            {% endfor %}
            new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel) {
            {% for obj in objects %}
                {{obj}} = channel.objects.{{obj}};
            {% endfor %}
            });
            """
            self.runJavaScript(Template(_script).render(objects=objects.keys()))
            for obj in self._objects:
                if isinstance(obj, Element):
                    self.runJavaScript(obj.script())


class WebPage(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        page = WebEnginePage(self)
        self.setPage(page)

        formobject = FormObject("formobject", self)
        formobject.numbersChanged.connect(self.on_numbersChanged)
        page.add_object(formobject)

        filepath = os.path.abspath(
            os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "new.html")
        )
        self.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filepath))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str, str)
    def on_numbersChanged(self, number1, number2):
        print(number1, number2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    web = WebPage()
    web.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE <html>
    <body>
        <form>
            Number 1:<input type="text" id="num1">
            <br>
            Number 2:<input type="text" id="num2">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" id="sub1">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are using the same html then the question is the same so it is a duplicate

Comment: I now that question and I have used the code of that question but now my problem is how to append or edit or remove a part of my html view.

Comment: 1) When do you want to remove it? 2) What part of HTML do you want append or edit or remove?

Comment: after calling that python function which has been called by that button.

Comment: That is the answer to my first question, what is the answer to my second question?

Comment: what is your second question?

Comment: *What part of HTML do you want append or edit or remove?*

Comment: I want to remove those inputs

Comment: Then place is information in your question

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You say: *I have viewed some html in qwebengineview.setHtml() and now I want to run a python function when clicking a button in that html view and then add some html to my html view which is the output of the function which I 've called.* but that is a very general requirement, and the questions in SO must be specific, so if you add: "I want that when the form button is pressed I want the inputs removed" then that question is concrete

Comment: On the other hand I have a question: Do you want to remove the text from the inputs or do you want to remove the inputs?

Comment: I want to remove the inputs.

Comment: read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57926683/how-to-change-a-part-of-html-in-pyqt5-qwebengineview?noredirect=1#comment102271722_57926683)

Comment: Sorry. I was eating my dinner. And because of that I didn't understand what have you pointed.

Comment: now just please tell me how to remove those inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove an element from the HTML you must do it with js, but the main problem in knowing when to do it, in the case of a form the page reloads so you must remove the “input” an instant after it is loaded for it a QTimer.singleShot (t, func) with an appropriate "t" can be used.

Considering the above and using the same code then the solution is

```
class WebPage(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        page = WebEnginePage(self)
        self.setPage(page)

        formobject = FormObject("formobject", self)
        formobject.numbersChanged.connect(self.on_numbersChanged)
        page.add_object(formobject)

        filepath = os.path.abspath(
            os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "new.html")
        )
        self.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filepath))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str, str)
    def on_numbersChanged(self, number1, number2):
        print(number1, number2)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(100, self.remove_inputs)

    def remove_inputs(self):
        self.page().runJavaScript(
            """
            function remove_by_id(_id){
                var elem = document.getElementById(_id);
                elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
            }
            remove_by_id("num1");
            remove_by_id("num2");
        """
        )
```

Comment: @icode What HTML do you want to add, where and when ?, I have already indicated that you should ask a specific question

Comment: for example I have a <div> and now I want to add some other tags to it or remove from it or edit them.

Comment: @icode Tell me a concrete example with the HTML that you have provided, but if you have noticed, you only have to use js to do those actions. Do you know anything about js?

Comment: Yes I now about js and I have tested an example and it works how do I want. Thank you very much.